# I want to find min in rows but max in column in c language by using matrix

Tags: c, matrix, max, min

```
#include <stdio.h>
//Matrix 5x5
int main()
{
    int i,j,a[5][5];
    printf("Enter Matrix A :\n");
//for scan numbers
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d,%d] = ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }
    printf("\nMatrix A:\n");
//for print matrix
    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
//Show answer
    printf("\nAnswer:\n");
//Display min and max like A[a,b] = x that make me confused

    return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner for coding and now so confused about how to find it I'm trying to solve it but can't and that why I'm here in stackoverflow.

I know I should find in row then in column but I don't know how to code it.

Sample is

Matrix A:

[2       3       3       4       1]

[12      5       6       7       9]

[9       2       7       9       1]

[3       1       4       5       6]

[7       4       6       10      3]

Answer:
A[2,2] = 5

Comment: Welcome to Stack overflow.
Your code creates a 5X5 matrix. Do you need min and max for each column/row or for the entire matrix?
If you provide sample input and output. It will be helpful.

Comment: Suggestion: make a function to find the minimum value (and index) in a row, then call that function for every row in your matrix and find the maximum.

Comment: it's min in row but max in column bro

Comment: If the matrix contains two such min in a row but max in the column. Then what is supposed to be the output?

Comment: the answer is 5 now look in row 5 is min in row and in column 5 is max in column, but i don't know how to code it

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int check(int arr[5][5],int r,int c)   /*Function to check is that element is lesser than all element in row and grater than all element in col*/
{
    int i;

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       if(arr[r][c]>=arr[r][i]&&i!=c)
            return 0;
    }

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
       if(arr[r][c]<=arr[i][c]&&i!=r)
            return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main()
{
    int i,j,a[5][5],flag=1;

    printf("Enter Matrix A :\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("A[%d,%d] = ",i+1,j+1);
            scanf("%d",&a[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("\nMatrix A:\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            printf("%d\t",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\nAnswer:\n");

    for(i=0;i<5;i++)
    {
        for(j=0;j<5;j++)
        {
            if(check(a,i,j))
            {
                printf("A[%d,%d]=%d",i+1,j+1,a[i][j]);
                flag=0;
                break;
            }
    }
    }

    if(flag)
    {
        printf("No Value");
    }

    return 0;
 }
```

If your matrix has more than one value like this(5) remove `break` and if you removed break this will print all value like this(5) otherwise it will print first value like this.

Note:The code can be optimized in better way but it is for simplicity and understanding.

Comment: I think that is better eliminate the check if is the same element and using `if(arr[r][c] > arr[r][i])` and `if(arr[r][c] < arr[i][c])` for the case of multiples minimal o maximal elements